# CollapsingToolbarLayout not showing custom title

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I can't seem to find the error in my code. The CollapsingToolbarLayout is not showing a title, even though I'm setting one. It shows the back button but not the title, and it is still the height of the normal Toolbar.

Setting a title on the Toolbar or getSupportActionBar() also doesn't work.

activity.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("My Title");
    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you trying to get by using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: @tachyonflux I'm going to add some content in the NestedScrollView later. My goal is to have a few lines of text in the CollapsingToolbarLayout that condense to one line when collapsed, but I need to figure out how to set a title before I can do that. I might also decide to add a background image later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I solved my problem: I need to manually specify the height of the AppBarLayout instead of setting it to wrap_content.